# How to make Pagination "next page" and "previous page" go to the specified href inside a form?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make a simple pagination page between the different parts of my form and they should be "active" (= have different display) when the appropriate part of the form is displayed.

Furthermore, I want to have "previous page" and "next page" using "«" and "»" brackets and make them set the targeted page to active **AND** load it.

I managed these first steps, and my "«" and "»" work to change the active display **but** I cannot find how to display the part of my form at the same time.

In conlusion, I have a **jquery** problem to set "«" and "»" so when they are clicked, they display the appropriate "next" or "previous" part of my form (referred by their id "step1" "step2" or "step").

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var pageItem = $(".pagination li").not(".prev,.next");
      var prev = $(".pagination li.prev");
      var next = $(".pagination li.next");

      pageItem.click(function() {
        pageItem.removeClass("active");
        $(this).not(".prev,.next").addClass("active");
     target = $(this).find( 'a.tab' ).attr('href');
  
     $('.case-content > div').not(target).hide();
  
     $(target).fadeIn(600);

      });

      next.click(function() {
        $('li.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
     // I think something should go here
      });

      prev.click(function() {
        $('li.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
     // and also here
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="caseform">
      <div class="center">
        <ul class="pagination">
          
          <li class="prev"><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>

   <li class="active"><a class="tab" href="#step1">1</a></li>
 
          <li><a class="tab" href="#step2">2</a></li>

          <li><a class="tab" href="#step3">3</a></li>
 
          <li class="next"><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    
    <form action="/case/createcase.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
      <div class="case-content">
        
        <div id="step1">
          <h2>Step 1<h2>
          <!-- some input text fields -->
        </div>

        <div id="step2">   
          <h2>Step 2</h2>
          <!-- some input text fields -->
        </div>
   
        <div id="step3">
          <h2>Step 3</h2>   
          <!-- some input text fields -->
        </div>
          
      </div><!-- case-content -->
    </form>
    </div>
```

The "«" and "»" should point to the href of the previous or next part of the form relative to the presently active part of the form.

However, in my code, they just "set" the li to active (display is ok) but do not point to the href inside the link.

Furthemore, even if I set "not(".prev,.next")", they still display as active when I click for example ".prev" from step 1 or ".next" from step 3.

If something is unclear, I would be happy to respond. I have an attached CSS file for the display if needed. I did not put it here to not make this code too long.

Comment: You need to use a GET parameter in the address bar URL to define what page you are at.

Comment: Could you show me how to do that ?

 Would it work even if I don't really change the page but just the display ? Because in my code I target div elements that are showed or not showed depending on the click, but I do not send the client to another page (same form, different parts show up)

Comment: What about this http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/ or http://pagination.js.org?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I managed to find a solution without requiring any js plugin. I'll post it here if anyone is interested.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var pageItem = $(".pagination a").not("#prev, #next");

  pageItem.click(function() {
    pageItem.removeClass("active");
    $(this).not("#prev, #next").addClass("active");

    target = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.case-content > div').not(target).hide();
    $(target).fadeIn(600);
  });

  $("#prev").click(function() {
    $('a.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
    if ($(this).hasClass("active"))
      $(this).removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
    if ($(".case-content div:visible").prev().length != 0)
      $(".case-content > div:visible").prev().fadeIn(600).next().hide();
    return false;
  });

  $("#next").click(function() {
    $('a.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
    if ($(this).hasClass("active"))
      // change below to next() if you want to put the brackets on the left
      $(this).removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
    if ($(".case-content div:visible").next().length != 0)
      $(".case-content > div:visible").next().fadeIn(600).prev().hide();
    return false;
  });

});
```

```css
h2 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.caseform {
  background: rgba(19, 35, 47, 1);
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 90%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  border-radius: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 4px rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.3);
}

.case-content>div {
  display: none;
}

.case-content>div:first-child {
  display: block;
}

.pagination a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
  background: rgba(160, 179, 176, 0.25);
  color: #a0b3b0;
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.pagination a.active {
  background: #CE0101;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.pagination a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="caseform">
  <div class="pagination center">
    <a id="prev" href="#">&laquo;</a>

    <a class="tab active" href="#step1">1</a>

    <a class="tab" href="#step2">2</a>

    <a class="tab" href="#step3">3</a>

    <a id="next" href="#">&raquo;</a>
  </div>
  <!-- pagination -->

  <form action="/case/createcase.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="case-content">

      <div id="step1">
        <h2>Step 1</h2>
        <!-- some input text fields -->
      </div>

      <div id="step2">
        <h2>Step 2</h2>
        <!-- some input text fields -->
      </div>

      <div id="step3">
        <h2>Step 3</h2>
        <!-- some input text fields -->
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- case-content -->
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: I fixed a `<h2>` that should have been `</h2>`. Then I noticed several remaining `</li>` tags, it looks like you removed the opening `<li>` tags.

Comment: Never mind, and thanks for posting a decent working sample.